# multithreading in java with exact number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an array of threads in java with the length of 24.
I want to run them but if I run more than two of them my computer will be shut down. 
how can I run just two of them in every moment? 
this is what I wrote but it doesn't work (after running this code my computer shut down) :

```
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[files.length];


    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File a = files[i];
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Function(a.toString());
                }
            });
    }

    Thread a = null,b = null;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < files.length) {
        if (!a.isAlive()) {
            a = threads[i];
            a.start();
            i++;
        }
        if (!b.isAlive()) {
            b = threads[i];
            b.start();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your computer shuts down when you try to run 3 threads? That's odd...

Comment: Looks like it would crash with a NPE before it even starts the first thread.

Comment: Computer shutdown? are you sure?

Comment: Besides of the odd reason for trying to run only two threads. Just use the higher level AP Ilike  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

Comment: Threads are the wrong abstraction for what you need. You need a fixed-size thread pool (such as the Executors class provides) to which you can feed Runnables. ExecutorService is the way to go.

Comment: @shmosel my function is very heavy, my RAM crashes after running 3 threads or more.

Comment: @tkausl I have seen that 2 threads started and some files generated, that means 2 threads are working fine but I don't know why my computer shut down, I think a third thread is starting

Comment: No matter how heavy, running a java application shouldn't crash your computer (and I doubt what you mean by RAM **crashes**).  At most you are going to get a out of memory exception.  If your machine crash, then it is a problem in your machine.  And, if it is the heavy work that is causing the problem, then it means it has nothing to do with threading.  It is meaningless to ask a question on this then.  You need to check what in your logic is causing the crash

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you can only run 2 threads, what do you need a thread pool for? It's like eating McDonald's fries sitting in a steak house. But then, you're probably not gonna ship your PC to Prod, so you need to design for running more threads. Let's talk when you can clearly articulate your use case.

Comment: i think ur hardware have an issue, a fault fan or cooling system specially for CPU, if ur threads are heavy duty, they will make a big load on the CPU and thus it will heat and shutdown is a self defense (by the CPU)

Answer (score 1):

If running that code shuts down your computer, then your computer is broken.

It is not even the threading, because your code will raise a NullPointerException at the first time it reaches `if (!a.isAlive()) {` because at this point a is null.

The Java Virtual Machine cannot shutdown your PC, no matter how bad the code is you write. In worst case the JVM will crash or Windows will shut it down, but a total shutdown clearly indicates an error with your hardware.